# awk to display differences in 2 files

Tags: awk

I am trying to display the count and differences (if any) between two files using `awk`. The `awk` below will display the unique count of `$3` in file2, but how do I also display the ids that were not found?  Thank you :).

**file1**

```
ACTA2
ACTC1
APC
APOB
BRCA1
BRCA2
```

**file2** (`ACTA2, ACTC1, APC are all unique so they are used in the count`)

```
chr10:90694965-90695138 ACTA2-1269|gc=52.6 639.7
chr10:90697803-90698014 ACTA2-1270|gc=50.2 347.6
chr15:35082598-35082771 ACTC1-254|gc=50.3 603.8
chr15:35085431-35085785 ACTC1-258|gc=54.8 633.8
chr15:35086866-35087046 ACTC1-259|gc=67.2 291.0
chr5:112043405-112043589 APC-1396|gc=70.1 334.8
chr5:112090578-112090732 APC-1397|gc=39.6 171.6
chr5:112102006-112102125 APC-1398|gc=33.6 52.3
chr5:112102876-112103097 APC-1399|gc=41.2 177.4
```

**awk**

```
awk -F '[- ]' '!seen[$3]++ {n++} END {print n " ids found)}' file2
```

**desired result** (`comes from file2` - already works)

`3 ids found` and APOB,BRCA1,BRCA2 missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets you pretty close to your desired output:

```
$ awk -F'[ -]' 'NR == FNR { seen[$0]; next } !seen[$3]++ { n++ }
END { print n " ids found"; for (i in seen) if (!seen[i]) print i " missing" }' file1 file2
3 ids found
APOB missing
BRCA1 missing
BRCA2 missing
```

It basically loops through the `seen` array and checks the value. If it hasn't been seen in the second file `!seen[i]` is true.

Answer (score 1):

here is a prototype

```
$ awk -F '[- ]' 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} 
               ($3 in a){delete a[$3]} 
                    END {for(k in a) printf "%s ",k; print "missing"}' file{1,2}

BRCA1 BRCA2 APOB missing
```

with right output formatting

```
$ awk -F '[- ]' 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} 
               ($3 in a){delete a[$3]; c++} 
                     END{printf "%s ids found and ", c; 
                         for(k in a) {printf "%s",sep k; sep=","} 
                         print " missing"}' file{1,2}

3 ids found and BRCA1,BRCA2,APOB missing
```

Comment: Thank you both very much :).